# Install Mono for Nuget Deployment in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget, mono

I have a repo that builds and deploys a Nuget package to a VSTS feed in Azure DevOps. It's been working great. But I ran out of free minutes :(

So now I am going to use a VMSS ado agent that is used for deployments into Azure App Services.(Linux)

So, I added pool: agentname to my yaml. But, I am now getting a mono error when pushing.

```
##[error]Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'mono'. Please verify either the 
file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the 
PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
```

The VMSS was not created by me, so I do not know if mono was installed. However, this agent is used to build and deploy .net core 5 apps, so??? I checked and I don't think it's installed (I am not familiar with Linux commands, but I tried: mono, find, which and all dictate no install).

Is there a way to install mono just for the nuget deployment (as part of the pipeline) or do I need to mess with the VMSS?

[image]

Comment: What kind of package are you building and why Mono is involved? .NET 5 is not Mono, so an agent machine that can compile .NET 5 apps can be Mono free. If you do want Mono on a Linux machine, add the installation steps to your CI script, https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin

Comment: That's a great question - I have no idea. That's the error that shows up in the logs. I thought that .NET5 included mono as part of its open source/cross compatible nature.

Comment: "I thought that .NET5 included mono as part of its open source/cross compatible nature." No. .NET 5 only contains the CLR runtime from the Mono open source project, but far from the usual "Mono" distribution. That's why "Unable to locate executable file: 'mono'Unable to locate executable file: 'mono'" is then expected.

Comment: I don't understand why it fails on the push - it builds just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering with the solution I used.

Mono must be installed on the agent machine if you're using Linux as your agent and using Nuget. Nuget uses mono on Linux. So that's that. If you can install mono on your Linux machine, that, *I think*, that is another solution. I did not find an easy way to install mono as part of the job - and I think that would be too heavy anyway (unless it was a check and if not installed, install).

Instead, since I am using Azure DevOps, I used the dotnet cli to push the package to the feed, which is remarkably, nearly identical to the Nuget version (the only change was the task)

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Push'
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush:'$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'your feed'
    publishVstsFeed: 'your feed'
    allowPackageConflicts: true
```

And I am back in!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/dotnet-commands#package-creation Deep down inside, a portion of NuGet lives inside .NET CLI.

Comment: `allowPackageConflicts` is not available actually. But the rest works.

Answer (score 1):

```
# apt install mono-complete
```

Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 27.